# Creating a .dat file in C++

Tags: c++, file, stdio, createfile, strcat

Hi everyone well  I have to create a file that is .dat with should be named whatever the user puts in and this file  contains the persons name (doesn't matter if the full name is together), date and his/her weight. Now the problem is that the file "name".dat is created but inside the file it should be just the users name instead in my program i shows up as "name".dat(just like the file name and extension).
Here is me code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Registro 
{
    int dia,mes,anio; //day,month,year
    float peso; //weight
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     FILE* archivo; 
     int  numero=0;
     char nombre[100],c;
     Registro regis;

     cout<<"Nombre del paciente: ";
     scanf("%s", &nombre);
     getchar();

     strcat(nombre,".dat"); 

     archivo = fopen(nombre, "a+");

     if(archivo)
     {
         cout<<"En que dia estamos?(dd): ";
         scanf ("%d",&regis.dia);
         cout<<"En que mes estamos?: ";
         scanf ("%d",&regis.mes);
         cout<<"En que anio estamos?(aaaa): ";
         scanf ("%d",&regis.anio);
         cout<<"Cual es su peso?: ";
         scanf ("%a",&regis.peso);
        fprintf(archivo,"\r\n# ");
    fprintf(archivo, " Nombre: %s  " " Dia: %d" " Mes: %d" " Anio: %d" " Peso: %g"
                , nombre, regis.dia, regis.mes, regis.anio , regis.peso );


        rewind(archivo);
        do
        {
                c = fgetc(archivo);
        if ( c == '#' )
        {
            numero++;
        }

        }while(c != EOF);

        cout<<"El numero de registros es de "<<numero;

          fclose(archivo);
     }
     else 
          printf("Error al crear archivo.");

     return 0;
}
```

I think where I'm wrong it this part:

```
strcat(nombre,".dat"); 

         archivo = fopen(nombre, "a+");
```

I've tried puting it like this:

```
archivo = fopen(nombre".dat", "a+");
```

and

```
archivo = fopen(nombre,".dat", "a+");
```

both of these without the

```
strcat(nombre,".dat");
```

Thank you guys in advanced.

Comment: Please use string instead of char arrays. And to be consistent with cout you should use cin. Also FILE* is something used in C code, I suggest the use of fstream (ofstream more specifically since youre writing to it and not reading from the file).

Comment: @Borgleader actually I think i do have to read the file since at the end of the program I have to count how many registries are there in the file.

Comment: Sorry, but I really didn't undestand what is your problem or what you want to achieve

Comment: @Gustavo Why not count them as you write them?

Comment: @TomásBadan My problem is that inside the file it should be the users name, for example "TomasBadan", but instead it shows up like this "TomasBadan.dat". Now i want to save the user name, the date he registers his/her weight, and his/her weight. And at the end it should appear on screen how many registries does that file have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this pieces of code:

```
 cout<<"Nombre del paciente: ";
 scanf("%s", &nombre);
```

you put inside `nombre` the name of a person. Then you do this:

```
 strcat(nombre,".dat");
```

so you append `.dat` to `nombre` what effectively becomes: `nombre.dat` and uses that to write into your archive

By the way, note this much more an 'C' question than an 'C++' question, once you are using, in this majority, 'C' functions.

To solve this, just create a new variable and populates it, like:

```
char filename[100];

strcpy(filename, nombre);
strcat(filename, ".dat");
```

Comment: Ok so basiclly there needs to be 2 variables 1 for user name and the other fot the file name.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, now i just have to start learn this diferences. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `.dat` to the variable containing the user's name, so you no longer have the name by itself. You need to use different variables for the user's name and the filename.

```
 char nombre[100], filename[100], c;

 cout<<"Nombre del paciente: ";
 scanf("%s", &nombre);
 getchar();

 strcpy(filename, nombre);
 strcat(filename,".dat"); 
 archivo = fopen(filename, "a+");
```

Comment: Just saw your post thank you it really helped and it showed how this to functions work couldn't get the hang of it until now. And for that I thank you even more.